# Vue.js When applying multiple filters a list, how can you display a count/total of the results

Tags: vue.js

lets say I have a large object of people. and I want to filter them by hair color and gender. Once the filtering has taken place - how can i display the total number of results?

here is some pseudo code to help explain:

```
Vue.filter('hairFilter', function(person, color){
  return person.filter(function( item ){
    return item.hair == color
  })
});

Vue.filter('genderFilter', function(person, gender){
  return person.filter(function( item ){
    return item.gender == gender
  })
});


<h1>Total Results: [TOTAL FILTERED RESULTS NUMBER HERE]</h1>
<ul>
<li v-for="person in people | hairFilter 'red'| genderFilter 'male'">{{person.name}}</li>
</ul>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a computed property and [`$eval`](http://vuejs.org/api/#vm-eval).

```
{
  computed: {
    filteredPeople: function () {
      return this.$eval("person in people | hairFilter 'red'| genderFilter 'male'");
    }
  }
}
```

Then in your template do like:

```
<h1>Results {{ filteredPeople.length }}</h1>
<ul>
  <li v-for="person in filteredPeople">{{ person.name }}</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Gold star for you, my friend!